# Visual C++ additional directories missing when received from version control

Tags: visual-c++, vcxproj

I have a Visual C++ project that I have developed on one computer and have committed it to a repository and pulled it onto another computer. When I open the solution and attempt to build it on the other computer, the solution won't build and upon checking (Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories) is empty along with the Linker Additional Dependencies. Is there something I'm missing in the repository? The repo has the solution and all of the newly written source and header files as well as the following file types in the project folder:

.vcxproj

.vcxproj.filters

The filters file seems to have all the directories in it but for some reason, the solution isn't recognizing it. Is there a way to correct this or do I have to go down the rabbit hole again and manually include the directories all over again?

Comment: No, these settings are stored in the .vcxproj file.  The standard mistake is forgetting to set them as well for other configurations and platforms and having the wrong one active.  So you'll probably have to do it one more time, now making sure that the comboboxes are set to "All Configurations" and "All Platforms".

Comment: Yep, I sure wasn't using All Configurations. Thanks for the assistance!